# Unable to add Column to table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, alter

I am trying to add a column to a table.To do so I am trying

```
ALTER TABLE requirements Modify COLUMN parent_id int(11);
```

but when I try to execute this query mysql does not respond for long.So each time I have to kill the query.

I have created the table using

```
CREATE TABLE requirements (requirement_id smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_id smallint(6) NOT NULL, 
    name varchar(255) CHARACTERSET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (requirement_id), 
    UNIQUE KEY requirement_product_id_name_idx (product_id,name), 
    UNIQUE KEY requirement_product_idx (requirement_id,product_id), 
    KEY requirement_name_idx_v2 (name) )
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=7365
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please help me know why I am not able to execute the Alter table query.I am new to database is there something wrong with my alter table query.

Comment: Did you try `ALTER TABLE requirements add COLUMN parent_id int(11);` since modify works for existing column not new.

Answer (score 1):

According to your table defintion parent_id seems to be a new column which you want to add so your query should be to add the column not modify.

Try this:

```
alter table requirements add column parent_id int(11);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b95a8)**

On a side note:

There needs to be a space between `CHARACTERSET` here

```
name varchar(255) CHARACTERSET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

should be

```
name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```